# Is $f$ an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

Take $R$ to be a commutative ring and $A \in R_{n} $ and the homomorphism $f: R^{n} \rightarrow R^{n}$ defined by the equation $f(B) = AB $ be surjective.

How do I show that this implies $f$ is an isomorphism (as in it's invertible)?

I have established that since it's surjective, it obviously has a right inverse but what about the left inverse?

Comment: Is $R_n$ the same as $R^n$? Is $AB$ just componentwise multiplication? In each component, the surjectivity of $b\mapsto ab$ shows that the ideal $\langle a\rangle$ is all of $R$, which implies that $a^{-1}$ exists, which gives the inverse map $r\mapsto a^{-1}r$.

Comment: @lookingatthemoon Based on context, I would assume $R_n$ is square matrices of size $n$ with entries in $R$. Is this correct?

Comment: @metalspringpro yes, that is correct. I thought that notation was common, so I didn't elaborate on it. Perhaps I am mistaken and it's just my lecturer who prefers such notation.

Comment: @GregMartin no, $R_{n}$ is the set of square matrices with entries from the commutative ring $R$ and $R^{n}$ is simply the cartesian product of $R$ with itself n times.

Comment: @lookingatthemoon I don't think it's a common notation, and can mean other things in the right context. I think $M_n(R)$ or $M_{n \times n}(R)$ would be more common notations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a map between $R^n$ and $R^n$ it is enough to determine what the map does to a basis.  For example, we could consider the standard basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$, where $e_i$, as a vector, has a $1$ in the $i$th spot and $0$'s elsewhere. Since $f$ is surjective, for each $i$, we can choose a $b_i$ such that $f(b_i)=e_i$. Now we can define a map $g:R^n \to R^n$ by defining $g(e_i)=b_i$ and extending by linearity.  Extending by linearity means if we are given $r \in R^n$, then, writing $r$ (uniquely) as $r=\displaystyle \sum^n_{i=1} r_ie_i$ where the $r_i \in R$, we then define $g(r)=\displaystyle \sum^n_{i=1} r_ig(e_i)=\displaystyle \sum^n_{i=1} r_ib_i$.

The maps $f$ and $g$ are inverses by construction.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see this is by the theory of determinant. Namely, since $x \mapsto Ax$ is surjective, we can find a matrix $B$ such that $AB = I$. Then applying determinant we obtain that $\det (A) \det (B) = 1$ and thus $\det (A)$ is a unit in  $R$. Then we have $adj (A) \cdot A = \det (A) \cdot I$ and we can write $\frac{1}{\det (A)}adj (A) \cdot A = I$ and so $A$ has a left inverse.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix for $adj(A)$.